# How to make sure a click event has an effect only on the intended class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Here is the important part of the code that executes.

Im trying to click on one element with a particular ID that relates to bookmarking the message but the element keeps triggering another click event that hides every div with the class 'messageCase' while at the same time attaching class messageOpen2 to the bookmark images ID which is very odd

the 'hidden' classes just hide all other message instances that contain 
The messageCase class.

```
var openMessageAnimationStrategy = function () {
    var openMessage = $(document).ready(function () {
        var divTarget = $("div.messageCase");

        $(divTarget).click(function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            target.toggleClass('messageOpen2');
            divTarget.addClass('hidden');
            target.removeClass('hidden');
        });
    });
};
```

Here is what the HTML looks like

```
<div class="messageCase">
    <div class="messageImageBox">
        <div id="messageImage">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="subjectLine">
        Subject Line Text
    </div>
    <div id="bookMarkImage">
        <img id="bookmarkStatus" class="savedMessage" src="notbookMarked64.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="activeBookmarks">
        {38} <br />
        Bookmarks <br />
        <br />
        9:53am
    </div>
    <div id="bodyPreview">
        Body Preview Text is light
    </div>
</div>
```

Every Time I use the Click event on bookmarkStatus to change the src of the image it causes the first click event to execute making everything disappear & the class messageOpen2 to be added to bookmarkStatus. I can include the CSS if necessary but ill list the code for the bookmarking function below

```
var bookmarkedStrategy = function () {
    var bookmarkedStrategy = $(document).ready(function () {
        var bookmarkStatus = $("#bookmarkStatus");
        var divTarget = $('messageCase');
      //below trying to remove the Class that was attached by the initial function while also changing the image SRC for the class bookmark
        $(divTarget).click(function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            divTarget.removeClass('messageCase2');
            bookmarkStatus.toggleClass('savedMessage');
        });
    });
};
```

I Think the main problem has to do with the initial function but I don't know what else could be wrong any ideas?

edit Here is the CSS that matters.

```
  .savedMessage {
         background-image: url("bookmarked64.png");
     }
    .messageOpen2 {
       height: 250px;

        }
    .messageCase {
        margin: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: aliceblue;
        height: 70px;
    } 
  #bookMarkImage {
        float:right;
        height:64px;
        width:64px;
        z-index:9999;
    }
  .hidden {
        display:none;
        max-height: inherit;



       }
 .activeBookmarks {
            float: right;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 13px;

            font-weight: 700;
            text-decoration: solid;

        }
```

Calling code

```
var bookmarkedthings = new MessageHandling(bookmarkedStrategy);
bookmarkedthings.greet();
var openMessage = new MessageHandling(openMessageAnimationStrategy);
openMessage.greet();
```

Comment: Please include css, so that i can generate you a snippet.

Comment: It's probably because divTarget isn't what you think it is - your code seems like it needs a closure around that variable.  Or, set `var divTarget = $("div.messageCase");` *inside* your event handlers.  Or simply use `this` instead of `divTarget` again inside the event handlers.

Comment: added the CSS to my question

Comment: @james I was trying to get Closure with the strategies I created, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @james I tried that initially but I needed the classes to be handled independently on click. when I do what you are suggesting and even with 'this' it effect all instances of 'messageCase' instead of just the one i click on like the code does now.

Comment: if e.target has class='hidden', ie display:none, how can you have clicked on it?  I don't really understand the concept, so it's hard to suggest a solution.

Comment: @james So what its doing is its setting all but what was clicked to hidden while expanding what was clicked by toggling the CSS class. there are multiple instances of the HTML listed above

Comment: I can only guess what happens inside the MessageHandling function, but I assume that both openMessageAnimationStrategy and bookmarkedStrategy are executed.  That would bind two event handlers to all messageCase divs.  And that would lead to the problematic behavior you're describing.

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to stop event bubbling I used event.stopPropagation(); works just fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing . in your bookmarkedStrategy function code `var divTarget = $('.messageCase');` Add dot and try again

Comment: Added the Dot but it still attaches 'messageOpen2' and makes everything disappear :(

Comment: Can you post your code and how are you calling your functions.